# How to group variables?

Tags: angular, typescript

How to group variables:

```
export let findbyc$: Observable<Object>;
export let findbyi$: Observable<Object>;
export let findbyo$: Observable<Object>;
export let findbyob$: Observable<Object>;
```

I need to group them like:

```
const ChildObservers {
    export let findbyc$: Observable<Object>;
    export let findbyi$: Observable<Object>;
    export let findbyo$: Observable<Object>;
    export let findbyob$: Observable<Object>;
}
```

Then somewhere in app I want to use it like: `ChildObservers.findbyc$`

Comment: How do you plan on setting the `findby` properties?  Because it sounds like you want to invoke functions.

Comment: I have to set it like: `ChildObservers.findbyob$ = this.httpClient.get();`

Comment: Do you strictly have to implemented it like that?  It appears that you're just looking to create a service class with public functions to make API calls.

Comment: Try `export const ChildObservers = { findbyc$: Observable<Object>, ... };`

Comment: Could you share an sample? I have to use  | async

Comment: So, I dont want to use service in template like: `httpService.findbyc() | async`

Comment: Or is it good idea to use service in template via async pipe?

Comment: It depends on your use case.  Async pipe will automatically unsubscribe for you.  Sometimes thats desired, sometimes it's not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want to do is defining a set of properties groupped but not initialized.
You should define an interface and export a variable of this type.

```
interface ChildObservers {
    findbyc$?: Observable<Object>;
    findbyi$?: Observable<Object>;
    findbyo$?: Observable<Object>;
    findbyob$?: Observable<Object>;
}

export const observers: ChildObservers = { };
```

Then, you can initialize those properties whenever you need to.

```
observers.findbyob$ = this.httpClient.get();
```

Moreover, I suggest you to define that interface generic, according to the generic argument of the `Observable<T>`

```
interface ChildObservers<TResult> {
    findbyc$?: Observable<TResult>;
    findbyi$?: Observable<TResult>;
    findbyo$?: Observable<TResult>;
    findbyob$?: Observable<TResult>;
}

export const obsersers: ChildObservers<Object> = { };
```

And, initialize it properly

```
obsersers.findbyc$ = this.http.get<Object>();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export class ChildObservers {
  public constructor(private readonly httpClient: HttpClient){}

  public findbyc$ = (): Observable<Object> => {
    return this.httpClient.get();
  };

  public findbyi$ = (): Observable<Object> => {
    return this.httpClient.get();
  };

  public findbyo$ = (): Observable<Object> => {
    return this.httpClient.get();
  };

  public findbyob$ = (): Observable<Object> => {
    return this.httpClient.get();
  };
}

// Example for calling APIs
class MyComponent {
  public constructor(private readonly childObservers: ChildObservers){}

  public myFunction(){
    this.childObservers.findbyc$.subscribe(result => {
      console.log(result);
    });
  }
}
```